# Text File Input ignore line of tabs

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I have a job in Pentaho with a Text File Input step reading from a tab delimited text file.  Sometimes when this file is given they have lines that are empty of data but the row is filled with tabs because they copied empty lines in excel.  Below is a screen shot of the 'empty' rows in Notepad++.

[image]

Is there a way to ignore lines like this?  I tried adding a filter entry with *Filter string* = number of tabs, *Filter position* = 0, *Stop on filter* = Y, *Positive match* = Y.  This filter didn't seem to have any effect.

When the job runs it treats all of these as NULL records which makes sense but then this causes the next job a Table output to fail.  If there is not a way to fix this with a text file input is there another job which can easily clean-up the bad records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I did more debugging I found out that the Filter tab did have the logic to achieve what I was looking for.  Instead of Filter string = number of tabs, Filter position = 0, Stop on filter = Y, Positive match = Y it needed to have Positive match = N.  After this change then it started working correctly.

Comment: From a maintenance point of view, using step Filter-Rows to test a mandatory field to be NOT NULL is superior to entering a certain amount of metacharacters in a place where we are supposed to specify real data substrings.

Answer (score 0):

You can check one or more field values using [Filter Rows](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Filter+Rows).

Your transformation would look like: Text Input -> Filter Rows -> Table Output.

Comment: From looking at how the Filter Rows works I would need to add a condition to see if each column individually is NULL and then if all are exclude that line.  I can do this with the Filter Row step but it would be nice if there was an easier way.  Is there a cleaner way to check all columns with Filter Rows?